# send the file to my asp.net webapi controller from angularjs

Tags: angularjs, file-upload

am trying to upload image file. Now what i need to send the file to my asp.net web api controller from angularjs. i tried several SO questions. (i dont know where am going wrong) its wont help me. can any one help me to solve it.

HTML

```
<input type="file" file="file" fil onchange="angular.element(this).scope().photoChanged(this.files)" />
                <img ng-src="{{ thumbnail.dataUrl }}"width="150" height="150" />
```

angular Controller

```
//this is to preview the uplaode image      
$scope.thumbnail = {
            dataUrl: 'adsfas'
        };
        $scope.fileReaderSupported = window.FileReader != null;
        $scope.photoChanged = function (files) {
            if (files != null) {
                var file = files[0];
                if ($scope.fileReaderSupported && file.type.indexOf('image') > -1) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                            $timeout(function () {
                                $scope.thumbnail.dataUrl = e.target.result;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
//after the button pressed
        $scope.AddBanner = function () {


 var request = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: urls.api + 'Banner/PostBanner',
                data: data,
                ContentType: multipart/form-data;
                processData: false,
                //data: JSON.stringify(dataObj)



            }).success(function (data, status) {
                alert('saved succesfully');
            })
        .error(function (error) {
            $scope.status = 'Unable to upload Banner Details : ' + error.message;
            console.log($scope.status);
        });

        };
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's better to use a directive for this. Like for example: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload . You'll get progress reporting etc with it and cross-browser compatibility problems solved. No need to invent the wheel again here.